# Get values from XML, that are noted as "Value=xx" not boxed in

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML file, that looks like this inside:

```
<Data>
    <INFO>
        ..
        ...
        <JOB_NAME value="filename.pdf"/>
        <useless_info value="some_info"/>
        <TIMESTAMP value="20120210075304"/>
        <more_useless_info value="012345"/>
        ...
        ..
    </INFO>
    <INFO>
        ..
        ...
        <JOB_NAME value="filename2.pdf"/>
        <useless_info value="some_info"/>
        <TIMESTAMP value="20120210073487"/>
        <more_useless_info value="012345"/>
        ...
        ..
    </INFO>
</Data>
```

What i want to do, is write specific info to strings, so that later on i can write these to a text file or new XML file.
I found this example here: http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-name/
And i have this code a little bit working.
Not fully, because it it not getting the values.
my code looks like this:

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(FileNameTextBox.Text);

    XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Data/INFO");
    foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
    {
        string jobName = xn["JOB_NAME"].InnerText;
        string timeStamp = xn["TIMESTAMP"].InnerText;
        MessageBox.Show(timeStamp + jobName);  //for testing

    }
```

I think this has to do with the fact that the info that i want to get, is not boxed in like `<box>info</box>`
What i cant find is how i could get the info in my caseout of the xml file now.
Could someone lent me a hand?
thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the JOB_NAME and TIMESTAMP child nodes of each INFO node, then get their attributes, then get the Value of the "value" attribute.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(FileNameTextBox.Text);

XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Data/INFO");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    string jobName = xn.SelectSingleNode("JOB_NAME").Attributes["value"].Value;
    string timeStamp = xn.SelectSingleNode("TIMESTAMP").Attributes["value"].Value;
    MessageBox.Show(timeStamp + jobName);  //for testing
}
```

Be careful with this though as you are likely to get a NullReferenceException if any of the INFO nodes don't contain both a JOB_NAME and TIMESTAMP Node, and also if either of those do not have an attribute "value".

To answer your comment below:

```
string vendorName = xn.SelectSingleNode("JOB_NAME").Attributes["vendor-name"].Value;
string mediaName = xn.SelectSingleNode("JOB_NAME").Attributes["media-name"].Value;
```

Comment: it already fails to get the first one, although it really is there. for testing i made a small file that only as 3 INFO groups, but on the first job_name it already misses it.

Comment: @Dante1986 - Sorry, I think the parameters to SelectSingleNode were incorrect. They shouldn't have the slah. I've edited above and I think that should do it. Regardless I think the idea of the above is correct but it may need tweaks to get it working correctly

Comment: Perfect! this seems to work. I think this was also what Filburt tried to explain, but i did not get right away.

Comment: +1 should give the OP the desired result. I'd give an extra +1 for pointing out that lurking `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: just 1 more question i want to add to this (if you still see this comment ;-))  what if i have something that has 2 values like this one: <NAME vendor-name="AA" media-name="BB"/>

Comment: it does not seem to work when there are more than 1 attributes in the node. just copy-pasting one of the other 2, to use it on a node that has multiple attributes, gives (again) a null refference exception  (changed "JOB_NAME" to NAME, but that does not seem to be it)

Comment: @Dante1986 - It should work. Yes you will need to change JOB_NAME to NAME in the xpath passed to SelectSingleNode. Are you sure that "DATA/INFO/NAME" exists in your xml, and then that each of those NAME nodes have "vendor-name" and "media-name" attributes? You should probably break the line up into multiple statements, i.e. xmlNode nameNode = xn.SelectSingleNode("NAME"); if (nameNode != null){xmlNode vendorNameAttribute = nameNode.Attributes["vendor-name"]; /* <-- This might throw an exception if vendor-name doesn't exist */ string vendorName = vendorNameAttribute.Value; } else {/* error */}

Comment: ah yes, it was me. I was overlooking the fact it was within a new sub-node.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in that innerText won't work because in your example 'value' is an attribute.

```
string jobName = xn["JOB_NAME"].Attributes["value"].Value;
string timeStamp = xn["TIMESTAMP"].Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Corrected and tested. This method or the SelectSingleNode should work fine.

Comment: mm strange. If i display the string, i get "System.Xml.XmlAttribute" but nothing of a value :/

Answer (score 0):

You should get the `Value` property of the attribute named "value" in your nodes:

```
string jobName = xn.SelectSingleNode("JOB_NAME").Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Comment: gives Nullrefference exeption on the test file, that really has all the nodes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over all `INFO` elements and read the contained `JOB_NAME` and `TIMESTAMP`s `value`attributes then **Tobsey's answer** is correct and will give you the desired result.

---

If you intend to query specific values from your Xml document you should use XPath queries instead of iterating over a set of nodes:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(FileNameTextBox.Text);

string jobName = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//JOB_NAME/@value").Value;
string timeStamp = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//TIMESTAMP/@value").Value;
```

---

**Update**

If you have repeating `INFO` nodes but just are interested in the first one you could change your query to just look at the first one:

```
string jobName = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//INFO[1]/JOB_NAME/@value").Value;
string timeStamp = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//INFO[1]/TIMESTAMP/@value").Value;
```

The Xpath query `//INFO[1]/JOB_NAME/@value` is a shorthand expression for `//INFO[position() = 1]/JOB_NAME/@value` and will examine the position of the node in  your Xml document.

---

*Beware! The simplified example above will fail if `.SelectSingleNode` returns `null`!*

Comment: the INFO group repeats itself over 100 times, but everything within the IFO group is the same every time. but there is a lot of info that i dont need in there. thats why i chose to use the foreach. maybe the example you have here should also do the trick. i'll give it a try

Comment: See my updated answer - using XPath can be a little complicated if you never used it befor but it's way more flexible than finding values by iterating over node sets.

Comment: i dont think i fully understand. i dont have any numbers in the info (edited my post to extend the xml example some more). but how can i let it count in that case? so i want to get them for each line, every time again, so i can "rewrite" a simple version. for example to a text line where every line has the 2 values comma seperated

Comment: The "counting" in this case happens inside the Xml parser. If you really want to iterate over every `INFO` node then Tobsey's answer is the one you'd want. If you actually want to transform your Xml document to a CSV file you could consider using Xslt - this would also free you from iterating over your nodes. If you are interested I'd update my answer to show you an Xslt example.